# Scrapy callback str issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run a scraper using Scrapy, I was able to do in the past using this code, but now I get a strange error.

```
 _rules =(Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(xpath_str)), follow=True,
          callback='parse_url'),)

 def parse_url(self, response):
     print response.url
     ...
```

Basically what I get back when I run it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 67, in _parse_response
    cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any ideas why this happens? I have a really similar code in another scraper which works?!

Here is the full code

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..model import Properties


class TestScraper(CrawlSpider):
      name = "test"
      start_urls = [Properties.start_url]

     _rules =( Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(Properites.xpath)), follow=True, callback='parse_url'), )

        def parse_url(self, response):
            print response.url
```

Comment: Do you have a function called `parse_url`? Then You need to specify `parse_url` instead of `'parse_url'`

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the `callback` inside the rules? Please post the complete code of your spider.

Comment: @falsetru I have a function parse_url, and have tried what you suggest, but it does not work.

Comment: @alecxe I am quite certain, as when I remove callback it does work. And the error suggests there is a problem in Rule class when it tries to call the callback. Here is the full code, quite simple.

Comment: @ilijaluve first or all, why is it `_rules` and not `rules`? Also, check the indentation.

Comment: @alecxe intendation is due to copying here, not a serious problem. For some reason the code failed as it was expecting _rules, and not rules. I had changed that, but it did not do much,

Comment: are you passing xpath to the start_urls?

Comment: @alexce it is the latest verison from github

Comment: @eLRuLL no only to those that are extracted from starturls.

Answer (score 0):

Change `callback='parse_url'` to `callback=self.parse_url`.